# CouchDB Futon won't delete database with name including +

Tags: curl, couchdb, couchdb-futon

According to the specs and to Futon CouchDB database names can contain a '+' however all my attempts to delete the database with both the Futon front end and curl fail.

With futon clicking on the delete button does nothing at all the modal stays there and there is no error message.

With curl it says the database does not exist.

My curl command is:

```
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:5984/colon+name
```

The exact error message is:

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}
```

Comment: While not ideal, you can delete the corresponding database file in `/var/lib/couchdb` if you can't through other means. (though I am surprised that `+` doesn't work, since it is a valid character in a URL)

Comment: I can't locate /var/lib/couchdb on either my local CouchDB or my remote (AWS) CouchDB